# Fetch Contact name and photo with cursor

Tags: android

```
public class ContactsListFragment extends ListFragment implements
        LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener
{

    private final String CURSOR_SORT_ORDER = Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
    private final String CURSOR_SELECTION = Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1";
    private final int CONTACT_ID_INDEX = 0;
    private final int CONTACT_KEY_INDEX = 1;

    private CursorAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // create adapter once
        Context context = getActivity();
        int layout = android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;
        Cursor c = null; // there is no cursor yet
        int flags = 0; // no auto-requery! Loader requeries.
        mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context, layout, c, FROM, TO, flags);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        // each time we are started use our listadapter
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
        // and tell loader manager to start loading
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }

    // columns requested from the database
    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    final static String[] PROJECTION =
    {
            Contacts._ID,
            Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY,
            com.ziepa.utils.Utils.hasHoneycomb() ? Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY : Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME 
    };

    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    private static final String[] FROM = 
    { 
        com.ziepa.utils.Utils.hasHoneycomb() ? Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY : Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME 
    };

    private static final int[] TO =
    { 
        android.R.id.text1 
    };

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args)
    {
        // load from the "Contacts table"
        Uri contentUri = Contacts.CONTENT_URI;

        // no sub-selection, no sort order, simply every row
        // projection says we want just the _id and the name column
        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), contentUri, PROJECTION, CURSOR_SELECTION,
                null, CURSOR_SORT_ORDER);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data)
    {
        // Once cursor is loaded, give it to adapter
        mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader)
    {
        // on reset take any old cursor away
        mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View item, int position, long rowID)
    {
        final Cursor cursor = mAdapter.getCursor();
        // Move to the selected contact
        cursor.moveToPosition(position);

        long contactId = cursor.getLong(CONTACT_ID_INDEX);
        String contactKey = cursor.getString(CONTACT_KEY_INDEX);

        final Uri contactUri = Contacts.getLookupUri(contactId, contactKey);
        //What should I do here?
    }
```

I have this fragment that's added to an activity, it successfully displays a list of contacts(their names). In the OnItemClick method, I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do to get the selected contact name and photo? Do I have to run another query with the Uri or is there a simpler way of getting this information.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet may be to use a custom adapter - extend BaseAdapter - that can return you an object from the adapters getItem()

I personally dont like cursor adapters for this reason. I would have built a list Contact models with all the fields you needed easily accessed, and then simply return that Contact model in the adapters getItem().